# Java Web Dev -- How to create folders in Browser

Tags: java, mysql

''=

im new to this conversations,
can anyone tell me how to create folders like this in browser ?
and i want to know what are the applications apart from Spring Tool Suit,MySQL....I have created a logging and welcome page up to now by authenticating the user

Example Page

[image: [1]]

Login page created

[image: [2]]

Comment: pls anyone ????

Comment: Shouldn't the question be related to HTML ? Or do you mean with Java ee?(which still outputs HTML).. can you maybe describe more what you want? (Create folders which represent a filesystem or do you just want to know how to create this with HTML CSS JavaScript??

Comment: yes it is by HTML CSS JavaScript. i just want to build a small file sharing system through the browser, as a example for a users in a office those who cannot use internal network.think that they can only access the internet..thnks alt for the reply

Comment: Take a look at jQuery File Tree : https://www.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-file-tree

Comment: hay gys...what are the things do i have to change when converting Angular files to Java

Comment: AngularJS is JavaScript it has nothing to do with Java